# VBA Jagged Array Duplicates

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, duplicates, jagged-arrays

I'm new to coding with VBA, and a beginner programmer in general. I have the following simple table (the data keeps getting inputted on daily basis, so it changes):

| Item # | Description | Date | Location | Plate | Load | Type | Rate | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | des1 | 30/1/21 | Site | ABC123 | 5 | One | typ1 | 100 |
| 0002 | des2 | 30/1/21 | Office | ACB465 | 4 | One | typ1 | 100 |
| 0003 | des3 | 30/1/21 | Office | ABC789 | 3 | One | typ1 | 100 |
| 0004 | des4 | 30/1/21 | Site | ABS741 | 5 | One | typ1 | 100 |
| 0005 | des4 | 31/1/21 | Office | ABC852 | 2 | One | typ1 | 100 |

I would like to filter this data by **specific date** first, then delete duplicates in **Location** while adding the **Load** for said duplicates.

For example, if I wanted to filter for **30/1/21**. It would end up as follows:

| Location | Load |
| --- | --- |
| Site | 10 |
| Office | 7 |

I would then want to put it in one summary cell as follows:

| Summary |
| --- |
| 10 Site, 7 Office |

I was able to filter the original table into jagged arrays. The code for that is:

```
For j = numberSkipD To numberRowsD
    If Worksheets("Disposal Fees").Range("F" & j).Value = Worksheets("Daily Tracking").Range("B2").Value Then
        For k = numberDisposalInformationRaw To numberDisposalLocation
            ReDim Preserve disposalLocation(numberDisposalLocation)
            disposalLocation(numberDisposalLocation) = Worksheets("Disposal Fees").Range("I" & j).Value
 
        Next
        numberDisposalLocation = numberDisposalLocation + 1
 
        For k = numberDisposalInformationRaw To numberDisposalLoad
            ReDim Preserve disposalLoad(numberDisposalLoad)
            disposalLoad(numberDisposalLoad) = Worksheets("Disposal Fees").Range("K" & j).Value
        Next
        numberDisposalLoad = numberDisposalLoad + 1
    End If
Next
```

I then tried to do the second table above (deleting duplicates and adding the values for said duplicates together) but it is giving me errors, not sure how to solve them. I know they're index errors, but don't know how to fix them. (Please help me with this part, here is the code)

```
Dim disposalInformationRaw As Variant
    Dim disposalInformationCooked As Variant
    Dim FoundIndex As Variant, MaxRow As Long, m As Long
        
    ReDim disposalInformationCooked(1 To UBound(disposalInformationRaw, 1), 1 To UBound(disposalInformationRaw, 2))
    
    MaxRow = 0
    For m = 1 To UBound(disposalInformationRaw, 1)
        FoundIndex = Application.Match(disposalInformationRaw(m, 1), Application.Index(disposalInformationCooked, 0, 1), 0)

        If IsError(FoundIndex) Then
            MaxRow = MaxRow + 1
            FoundIndex = MaxRow
            disposalInformationCooked(FoundIndex, 1) = disposalInformationRaw(m, 1)
        End If

        disposalInformationCooked(FoundIndex, 2) = Val(disposalInformationCooked(FoundIndex, 2)) + Val(disposalInformationRaw(i, 2))
    Next m
    
    Range("G1").Resize(MaxRow, UBound(disposalInformationCooked, 2)).Value = disposalInformationCooked
```

I don't think I'd have much trouble finalizing the third part (the summary), but if you know how to do it, please feel free to share how you would approach it. I mostly need help with the second part. I would be more than happy to edit and provide more information if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need the second table, or just the final summary?

Comment: I need to get the final summary. Maybe there is a better way to approach it than what I did, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sum Unique

**Disposal Fees**

[image]

**Daily Tracking**

[image]

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TESTsumByValue()
    
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Disposal Fees"
    Const lCol As Long = 3
    Const kCol As Long = 4
    Const sCol As Long = 6
    Const SumFirst As Boolean = True
    Const KSDel As String = ":"
    Const IDel As String = ", "
    ' Destination
    Const dstName As String = "Daily Tracking"
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Define Source Range (You may have to do something different).
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = wb.Worksheets(srcName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Write Criteria to variable.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = wb.Worksheets(dstName).Range("B2")
    Dim Criteria As Variant: Criteria = drg.Value
    
    ' Use function to get the result.
    Dim s As String
    s = sumByValue(Criteria, srg, lCol, kCol, sCol, SumFirst, KSDel, IDel)
    Debug.Print s ' "10:Site, 4:Bathroom, 4:Office"
    
    drg.Offset(, 3).Value = s ' writes to 'E2'
    
End Sub

Function sumByValue( _
    ByVal LookupValue As Variant, _
    rng As Range, _
    ByVal LookupColumn As Long, _
    ByVal KeyColumn As Long, _
    ByVal SumColumn As Long, _
    Optional ByVal SumFirst As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal KeySumDelimiter As String = ": ", _
    Optional ByVal ItemsDelimiter As String = ", ") _
As String
    
    ' Validate range ('rng').
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    ' Write values from range to Data Array ('Data').
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rng.Value ' 2D one-based array
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim vKey As Variant ' Current Key Value
    Dim vSum As Variant ' Current Sum Value
    Dim i As Long ' Data Array Row Counter
    
    ' Create a reference to Unique Sum Dictionary (no variable).
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' 'A = a'
        
        ' Loop through Data Array ('Data') and write and sumup unique values
        ' to Unique Sum Dictionary.
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            If Data(i, LookupColumn) = LookupValue Then
                vKey = Data(i, KeyColumn)
                If Not IsError(vKey) Then
                    If Len(vKey) > 0 Then
                        vSum = Data(i, SumColumn)
                        If IsNumeric(vSum) Then
                            .Item(vKey) = .Item(vKey) + vSum
                        Else
                            .Item(vKey) = .Item(vKey) + 0
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        
        ' Validate Unique Sum Dictionary.
        If .Count = 0 Then Exit Function
        
        ' Redefine variables to be reused.
        ReDim Data(1 To .Count) ' Result Array: 1D one-based array
        i = 0 ' Result Array Elements Counter
        
        ' Write results to Result Array.
        If SumFirst Then
            For Each vKey In .Keys
                i = i + 1
                Data(i) = .Item(vKey) & KeySumDelimiter & vKey
            Next vKey
        Else
            For Each vKey In .Keys
                i = i + 1
                Data(i) = vKey & KeySumDelimiter & .Item(vKey)
            Next vKey
        End If
    
    End With
    
    ' Write the elements of Data Array to Result String.
    sumByValue = Join(Data, ItemsDelimiter)

End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach using a dictionary.

```vb
dim dict, rw as range, locn, k, msg, theDate

set dict= createobject("scripting.dictionary")

theDate = Worksheets("Daily Tracking").Range("B2").Value

'adjust table range as required
for each rw in worksheets("Disposal Fees").range("F6:K100").rows
   if rw.cells(3).Value = theDate Then              'date match?
       locn = rw.cells(4).Value                     'read location
       dict(locn) = dict(locn) + rw.cells(6).Value  'add load to sum
   end if
next rw

'loop over the dictionary keys and build the output
for each k in dict
    msg = msg & IIf(len(msg) > 0, ", ", "") & dict(k) & " " & k
next k

debug.print msg
```

Comment: I think this is correct, but I think I am messing up the fill in the blanks

I filled them as follows, and get some errors:
`[table range here` as 
```
worksheets("Disposal Fees").range("F6:K")
```
`[location col]` as ```worksheets("Disposal Fees").range("I6:I")```
`[load col]` as ```worksheets("Disposal Fees").range("K6:I")```

The worksheet I am using as a reference for this is called "Disposal Fees"
The columns are:
F: date
I: Location
K: Load

Comment: For `rw.cells([here])` just put the column number in the row